# How to upgrade Django app from 1.6.11 to 1.8 when makemigrations crashes?

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm following the instructions to upgrade a Django app from Django 1.6.11 to 1.8.1. I've deleted all the migrations save for the **init**.py. I then run:

```
manage.py makemigrations
```

and it crashes with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Users/dwatson/Environments/website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
File "/Users/dwatson/Environments/website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Users/dwatson/Environments/website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/Users/dwatson/Environments/website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Users/dwatson/Environments/website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 143, in handle
  self.write_migration_files(changes)
File "/Users/dwatson/Environments/website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 171, in write_migration_files
  migration_string = writer.as_string()
File "/Users/dwatson/Environments/website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 166, in as_string
  operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
File "/Users/dwatson/Environments/website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 124, in serialize
  _write(arg_name, arg_value)
File "/Users/dwatson/Environments/website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 75, in _write
  arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(item)
File "/Users/dwatson/Environments/website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 303, in serialize
  item_string, item_imports = cls.serialize(item)
File "/Users/dwatson/Environments/website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 377, in serialize
  return cls.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
File "/Users/dwatson/Environments/website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 268, in serialize_deconstructed
  arg_string, arg_imports = cls.serialize(arg)
File "/Users/dwatson/Environments/website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 465, in serialize
  "topics/migrations/#migration-serializing" % (value, get_docs_version())
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <bound method AccountManager.gen_num of <coreapi.models.AccountManager object at 0x103925450>>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
For more, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing
```

This function is a method defined in the AccountManager class, which derives from models.Manager:

```
def gen_num(self):
    max_digits = 9
    candidate = random.randint(0, 10**max_digits)
    return candidate
```

I've inspected the return candidate line and as expected, it's an int.

I assume that this method is being introspected because it is set as the default for the associated field:

```
num = models.PositiveIntegerField(
    _('Num'), help_text=_('Number, automatically-generated'),
    unique=True, blank=True, null=True, default=AccountManager().gen_num
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to follow the advice given here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing

That is, move the function from the class body of the Manager to the module body:

```
def gen_num():
    max_digits = 9
    candidate = random.randint(0, 10**max_digits)
    return candidate
```

After this change, makemigrations completes successfully.